# Force curves to appear in front of mesh

Tags: mesh, obj, curve-modifier, viewlayers

Fairly new so I'm playing around with OBJ mesh imports from SketchUp and Rhino. When I bring in an object, I would also like these lines to display. So, I import them as well in the form of curves, but they always appear in the same plane and therefore are occluded. Any ideas to force them to stay on top? I don't want to use the 'in front' option because then they are visible through the object.[image: Blender Screenshot].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your curve a very small bevel:

[image]

<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>-drag this value, or confirm it with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> to set it for all selected curves.

If for some reason (those curves are used elsewhere) you don't want to modify the bevels nor duplicate the curves (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> Linked Duplicate would keep them synchronized in regards to the splines data), you can move them to a (new) collection (<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd>), and then add a new object and add a geonodes modifier to it:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, this works. Thank you for the advice!